# Diablo III Installation Size

Tags: diablo-iii, pc, macos

> What is the size of Diablo 3's files with patch 2.01 ?

On my computer, the size of Diablo 3's installation (2.01) is about 30 GB (and I haven't download the full patch yet).

Is it really so much to have the full game or is it because there are trash files?

If I remember correctly, at the beginning the game was less than 5 GB (right?). Is there any way to make it smaller?

Comment: Also, Blizzard was recommending that, if you have size issues, to uninstall and get the latest from their website.

Comment: This is something I've seen from Blizzard with all their newer games, WoW, SC2, and Diablo 3 have all had nasty bloat if you install from a really early install and then patch your way up.  They don't and haven't really ever cleaned up their patch files properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are bloat/trash files.

Blizzard has recommended to uninstall and re-install from their website if you have size restrictions. The original install plus patches take up a lot more room then the most recent install from the website.

The original file size was 8.3 GB for the installed game [See here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4926624077)

EDIT: I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I did a fresh re-install with Reaper of Souls expansion. The final file size for the entire Diablo III folder is (currently) 14.7 GB. The Battle.Net launcher takes another 219 MB. During the re-installation, I downloaded a new 5.7MB installation exe file. The instructions recommended that I have 200MB free for Battle.Net and 25 GB free for the Diablo III installation.

Comment: Any info on the size if someone does a fresh reinstall for the current version? Now that I read this, I'm considering whether to update or reinstall next time I play D3.

Comment: To be fair the installer is suppose to optimize your installation at some point.  So if you have an unoptimized instllation the reason is your installation has not been optimized.  I would install the patch and let the installer do it optomization.

Comment: My folder is also 14.8 GB and this is after optimization.