# Why does Diablo 3 insist on downloading 18gig when I try and install from DVD?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the abandonment of the auction house, and the upcoming Reaper of Souls expansion, I've decided to reinstall Diablo 3.

I don't have the fastest of Internet connections, and it has a monthly quota, so I dug out the original DVD to install from that. Before installing, it downloads some updates, then launches Battle.net client, and then decides it's just going to download an entire 18gig. It doesn't appear to have copied anything from the DVD. Can I not save some download by getting it to at least install *some* files from the DVD?

Comment: The game is about the Lord of the Purgatory. What did you expect?

Comment: I don't really know anything about it, but I would guess those are files that were introduced after the DVD was made, like patches and other content. I could be wrong, though, because I am not a Blizzard gamer, so I am really unfamiliar with their usual style.

Comment: Ok, for real now: With what speed does it download? With Battlefield 3, Origin "wanted to download" the files, but it had ~9 MB/s, which wasn't possible with my internet connection. It just showed "downloading" while reading from disc. May you compare that? A standard disc reading reaches to 9 MB/s.

Comment: It's definitely *downloading*, I monitor network activity in task manager, and the speed is my DSL speed, roughly 500k/sec.

Comment: I just deleted my 'answer' - firstly because it was intended to be a comment (wrong button, dang mobile site / phone), secondly based on your clarification that it's definitely downloading from the internet. So ignore it if you can see it! :)

Comment: It's likely that you're downloading the new Battle.net launcher and Diablo updates.

Answer (score 5):

The DVD doesn't have all of the patches, and there have been quite a lot. You can install all the main files for the game, but in order to play the game you will have to download all of the necessary patches, which aren't on the DVD.

Comment: Wow, that's a *lot* of patches. Incidentally, the first time I tried, it definitely did not install files from the DVD, it went straight to downloading. I've since managed to get it to install *some* files from the DVD. But it sounds like the game has been so heavily patched that very few of the files from the DVD are relevant now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Diablo III Installation Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157993/diablo-iii-installation-size)

which seems to imply that its better to just download the latest version straight from the site and not just the original DVD to install + patch.

Also, while I have no ideas on Blizzard's patching optimizations, applying multiple patches say 1.1 -> 1.20 will in the most naive implementations end up as doing a diff with each previous patch and making changes (i.e. patch 1.1 -> 1.2, then 1.2 -> 1.3 etc.) Obviously, its not going to be like this for D3 or any other commercial game, but there is still a chance of have to do multiple steps to patch existing files.

In conclusion, it may be faster to just aim for a clean install instead of patching all the way from the base version.

Comment: From that link: "The original install plus patches take up a lot more room then the most recent install from the website" - Say *what*? That's just crazy. I managed to get it to install *some* files from the DVD by uninstalling everything and trying again. But now it sounds like the only thing I'll have accomplished is wasting some disk space?

Comment: Its too bad we don't have numbers on the sizes for fresh install vs patched, both in terms of disk space and net traffic - atleast, I couldn't find any details :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Start the Installation from the DVD. Wehn Battle.net pops up, select the Gear in the Corner of the Battle.net app and there select the "Offline" Option.

It now should install from DVD and Patch the rest as you bring it Online after the Installation.

Apparently now this does not work either, see comments.

Comment: I can't find any "Offline" option. The gear in the corner offers "Settings" and "Pause all Updates". The "Settings" offer a myriad of options, but no "Offline" option that I can find.

Comment: Oh you're right, it seems this Option is no longer available in the current Battle.net. I just checked myself. Have you then tried to disconnect from the internet entierily and then start the intallation?

Comment: "We could not connect to the battle.net patch service. Please check your internet connection and try again." Installing while offline doesn't appear to be possible.